# Cassandra-all dependency failing

Tags: java, maven, cassandra, gradle, datastax-java-driver

I have included cassandra-all in my gradle dependencies list. Here is it:

```
compile 'org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all:2.1.0-beta2'
```

But when I am trying to build, it is failing with the following exception:

```
> Could not find ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.12.                                      
  Required by:                                                                               
      MAPro_Transactor:mapro-commons:1.0                                                     
      MAPro_Transactor:mapro-commons:1.0 > com.adaequare.mapro.model:mapro-model:2.0-SNAPSHOT
> Could not find io.netty:netty:4.0.17.Final.                                                
  Required by:                                                                               
      MAPro_Transactor:mapro-commons:1.0 > com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.0.1
> Could not find ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.12.                                         
  Required by:                                                                               
      MAPro_Transactor:mapro-commons:1.0 > org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all:2.1.0-beta2    
> Could not find ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.12.                                      
  Required by:                                                                               
      MAPro_Transactor:mapro-commons:1.0 > org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all:2.1.0-beta2    
> Could not find com.github.stephenc:jamm:0.2.6.                                             
  Required by:                                                                               
      MAPro_Transactor:mapro-commons:1.0 > org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all:2.1.0-beta2    
> Could not find io.netty:netty:4.0.17.Final.                                                
  Required by:                                                                               
      MAPro_Transactor:mapro-commons:1.0 > org.apache.cassandra:cassandra-all:2.1.0-beta2
```

I see that the dependencies are not really present in Maven repository. Thought I would go to the site, manually download the jars and put it into maven local repository. But I could not find com.github.stephenc:jamm:0.2.6 jar. Have some one else faced the same issue? Please suggest how to go forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven repository artifacts are broken. I am asked to use the following link to download the snapshot:

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/cassandra-2.1

Here is the bug raised for it in Cassandra JIRA: [CASSANDRA-7218](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7218)

The solution is also mentioned there.